# disabled property on button

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple angular code like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
            <input type="number" #mytext (keyup)="onclickfunc(mytext.value)">
            <button [disabled]="myVar==0" > Test </button>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  myVar=0;

  onclickfunc(mytext){
    this.myVar=mytext;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the button should become disabled when `myVar` is 0. The code works fine as it is. But if I change `[disabled]="myVar==0"` to `[disabled]="myVar===0"`, it acts strangely. I mean, even if I type 0 in the input box, the button doesn't become disabled.

Could you please explain the reason?

Comment: Because when you type it into the text box, it is no longer a number, it becomes a string (i.e. it becomes `"0"` instead of `0`). Therefore `=== 0` will always be false, as the `===` performs strict comparison

Comment: Thank you.
I have even tried `[disabled]="myVar.value===0"`, but this didn't help either.

Comment: @MaYaNicolson You should try `[disabled]="value === '0' "` instead, which will work as it will compare string with string

Comment: Thank you. But I need the button to be `disabled` on load.

Comment: Then set the initial value of `myVar = '0'`

Comment: Or I can keep `myVar = 0`  as it is, and change the body of `onclickfunc()` to :  `this.myVar=+mytext;`.

Comment: Exactly, or call `parseInt(myText)` which is a bit more explicit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168998/discussion-between-maya-nicolson-and-user184994).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `===` operator checks value and type while the `==` operator only checks value.
For example :

```
1 == "1" -> true
1 === "1" -> false (because types are not equal)
```